# Unresolveable CORS Error for react app trying to call firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I've been trying to resolve a CORS error for the last three hours and have tried everything. I'm using create-react-app and created this page:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null);
  function fileSelected(e)
  {
    setFile(()=> e.target.files[0]);
  }
  function uploadFile()
  {
    console.log(file)
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', file, file.name)
    axios.post('https://us-central1-athelasapp.cloudfunctions.net/uploadFile', fd)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="file" onChange={fileSelected}/>
      <input type="submit" onClick={uploadFile}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and I uploaded a google cloud function which uploads the image:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const Busboy = require("busboy");
const os = require("os");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const gcconfig = {
  projectId: "athelasapp",
  keyFilename: "athelasapp-firebase-adminsdk-yojnp-1e9141a009.json",
};

const {Storage} = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const gcs = new Storage(gcconfig);
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions


exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest(app);

app.post("/", (req, res) =>{
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: "Method Does Not Work",
    });
  }
  const busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
  let uploadData = null;

  busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) =>{
    const filepath = path.joing(os.tmpdir(), filename);
    uploadData = {file: filepath, type: mimetype};
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
  });

  busboy.on("finish", ()=>{
    const bucket = gcs.bucket("athelasapp.appspot.com");
    bucket.upload(uploadData.file, {
      uploadType: "media",
      metadata: {
        metadata: {
          contentType: uploadData.type,
        },
      },
    });
  }).then(() => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Method Works!",
    });
  }).catch((err) =>{
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Method Failed!",
    });
  });
  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
});
```

but I keep on getting this error no matter what I try
[image]

How can I solve this error. I've tried a number of things: deploying the website to see if it's a local host issue, changing the proxy, adjusting the react app configs, changing cors settings.

Comment: You have to set the CORS headers in your api response.  See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests

Comment: @James I already tried that and it didn't work. I updated the function in google cloud functions to make anyone be able to call the endpoint but that seems like a bandaid solution. How can I authorize just my app.

Comment: You can use your app's domain instead of "*" in access-control-allow-origin header.

Comment: try changing the cors origin to your url of the react app instead of true, Example: "http:// localhost:3000", and make sure theres no "/" at the end of the url

Comment: From reading the comments on the answer below, it seems you've solved your CORS problem. Could you please either [edit] this question to bring it up to date or accept the answer and ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `CORS` middleware to continue the preflight. Frontend javascript prevents communication to any location/address to other domains. Here, In your case, you might be calling firebase cloud function from localhost or some other domain that is different from cloud function's domain.
Here is how you can configure it in the cloud function

```js
// whitelist your domain or provide true to whitelist all domains
const cors = require("cors")({origin: true});
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {}) // call the CORS middleware
  ....
});
```

After configuring CORS, the request will continue.

Comment: that was what my code was originally but it didn't seem to work. It threw the same error. It only seemed to work when I let all users access my firebase function in its permissions

Comment: Yup, permission could be issue but in the case of permission, it doesn't return `CORS` error.

Comment: Oh gotcha! @Kiran Maniya I fixed the CORS error but it now throws "POST https://us-central1-athelasapp.cloudfunctions.net/uploadFile 500" I isolated it to busboy but I'm not sure what my error is? Can you tell from looking at it

Comment: You need to post the function code or the error to determine.